# How to proof with Sympy that a given Cartesian equation can be written as a given polar equation

Tags: python, sympy, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

i have an assignment on sympy and am struggling with the following question:

> "Prove with the help of Sympy that 4*(x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> -ax)<sup>3</sup> = 27*a<sup>2</sup>*(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> can be written using r = 4a*cos(theta/3)<sup>3</sup>".

I have tried to substitute `x = r*cos(theta)` and `y = r*sin(theta)`.

Then I tried `sp.solveset(eq, r)` but I only got a very longset of {}, nothing like the given polar equation.

Does anyone know how to do this (I can use sympy and numpy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code builds the equation from its left hand side and right hand side. Then the [change of variables to polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) is performed using [substitution](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution).

The resulting trigonometric expression is then simplified, and it turns out to be zero after simplification. So any pair/tuple `(x,y)=(r*cos(theta),r*sin(theta))` is a solution.

```py
from sympy import *
a,x,y,theta = symbols('a x y \Theta', real=True)
init_printing(use_latex=True)

lhs = 4 * (x**2 + y**2 - a*x) ** 3
rhs = 27 * a**2 * (x**2 + y**2)**2
f = lhs - rhs

r = 4 * a * cos(theta/3)**3
display(f,"----")
f = f.subs(x,r*cos(theta))
f = f.subs(y,r*sin(theta))
display(f,"----")
f1 = f
display(simplify(f))


# format for wolframalpha
t = symbols('t')
f1 = f1.subs(theta,t)
import re
f1 = re.sub("\*\*","^",str(f1))
print("----")
print("wolframalpha expression: solve ", str(f1)," over the reals")
```

To double-check this, at the end, a [wolframalpha query is also generated](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-27*a%5E2*%2816*a%5E2*sin%28t%29%5E2*cos%28t%2F3%29%5E6+%2B+16*a%5E2*cos%28t%2F3%29%5E6*cos%28t%29%5E2%29%5E2+%2B+4*%2816*a%5E2*sin%28t%29%5E2*cos%28t%2F3%29%5E6+%2B+16*a%5E2*cos%28t%2F3%29%5E6*cos%28t%29%5E2+-+4*a%5E2*cos%28t%2F3%29%5E3*cos%28t%29%29%5E3), which confirms the solutions.

[image]